# Complementation of Adjectives

Tags: complementation

I have four questions regarding classifying phrases complementing adjectives. I start with some examples:

> (1) She was hesitant *to tell her parents*. 
>   (2) The boss was anxious *to promote sales*. 
>   (3) Are you afraid *of spiders*? 
>   (4) We were shocked *by the news*. 
>   (5) I was delighted *that she was chosen*. 
>   (6) I am curious *what color it is*.

For (5) and (6), because of ***that-*** and ***what- clauses***, I classify them as **Noun Phrases**. If there are any **Conjunctions** such as *where* and *when*, the phrases that containt them will be considered **Noun Phrases**?

For (1) and (2), I am wondering whether or not should I classify them as **Verb Phrases** or ***to-Infinitive Clauses*** instead?

For (3) and (4), except for *to*, any prepositions showing up on these phrases will help me to identify them as **Prepositional Phrases**. However, is there any possibility that some of them might belong to another group of phrases?

Please help me.

I forgot to post the last question. I will post it when the three first questions are answered.

Comment: A very nice question +1). It would be better if you could split the question into three so that you can have a more definitive answer. One question per post is better.

Comment: For the OP, you may find this page useful: https://www.tu-chemnitz.de/phil/english/sections/linguist/real/independent/eafrica/Diss_Diana/dissch4-1.htm

Comment: *Where we used to live* was better. *When my sister died* was a hard time for us all.

Comment: @Rathony Sorry about the combination, I didn't think of this before.

Comment: Don't worry. You have a great answer below and next time when you have a question, try to be more specific focusing on what bothers you most with what you understand and you don't. You can ask as many questions as you want. Good luck.

Comment: @DamkerngT. Your page is so helpful but I just need some of them. My research is quite narrow compared to that of the page you provided. Thanks for your great help.

Comment: @Rathony Thanks again for your kindness. I have been surfing the forum for years but rarely posted questions. It is great to be given such helpful advice and warm welcome.

Comment: @AlanCarmack Thanks for your examples, however, I wonder which adjectives should I use so I can use both **_where-_** and **_when-_ clauses**?

Answer (score 2):

The adjectives in 1 and 2 have non-finite clauses as Complements. The clauses are realised as verb phrases. In other words they are clauses with verb phrases inside them.

4 and 5 include preposition phrases. They cannot be any other type of phrase, because they are headed by prepositions!

In example 5, *delighted* has a declarative content clause as a Complement.

In example 6, the adjective *curious* is taking an interrogative content clause as a Complement.

Comment: In the first place, I intended to classify Complements of Adjective(s) according to word patterns such as Adj + about and I wondered maybe I should divide them into 2 groups, 1 with finite clauses (what/ that clauses) and 1 with non-finite clauses (to-Infinitive clauses and clauses with the other prepositions).

However, as I read your explanations of examples 5 and 6, should I try to describe their functions/ natures (for example, a declarative content clause)? If yes, can you tell me any source of information that tells me about such contents that you mentioned?

Comment: @HồQuangTrung *A students introduction to English grammar* Huddleston & Pullum, 2005 is a very good place to start. I'd definitely buy it! But you can read it at [Slideshare here](http://www.slideshare.net/MrMinhajahmed/a-students-introduction-to-english-grammar)

Comment: Fortunately, I have managed to find one e-book.On page 118 (126/ 320), the authors mentioned two examples that I wanted to ask a question about them, I write it right here.

Comment: In the cases of: _busy **making cakes**_ and _difficult **for us to see**_, which groups of phrases that you think they belong to?The authors classified them as **Subordinate Clauses** compared with **Prepositional Phrases** but in my study I only prefer phrases (which is for the theoretical background part).

Comment: @HồQuangTrung well there is no preposition in *busy making cakes*, so *making cakes* cannot be a preposition there. The word *for* in *for us to see* isn't a preposition either, it is a subordinator used to introduce an infinitival clause. So in both of those two cases there is no preposition phrase. [However in something like *I'm scared of flying* you have a preposition phrase complement which *contains* a subordinate clause].

Comment: Great thanks for your explanations. I still got stuck with _for us to see_. However, which group of phrase that you put _(busy) making cakes_ in, **Noun Phrase** like _that- and what-clauses_?

Comment: @HồQuangTrung *Busy making cakes* is an ajdective phrase. *Making cakes* is a non-finite gerund-participle clause.

Comment: I use the examples of **Cambridge**:

We often use _for_ to introduce the person or people receiving something:
She bought a teapot _for her sister_.

Is _for_ still **Conjunction** as in the example above?